# Why does the beamer foreground color change colors of an included PDF file?

Tags: beamer, graphics, color

I have vector graphic created with Adobe Illustrator CS4 saved as PDF, it looks like:

[image]

You can download the PDF [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/neu6am928l0swol/dummy.pdf?dl=0).

**As you can see, the lines are black.**

---

If I include the PDF with `\includegraphics` in a beamer document which has a changed foreground color, all lines of my graphic get colored in that color!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{dummy.pdf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Oh yes, that's unexpected.

**What goes wrong? Is that really intended behaviour?**

**How do I get my lines black again?**

If it's a problem related to the `graphicx` package, I'd prefer a solution by that package. But a beamer workaround would be fine as well. I tried to locally set

```
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=black}
```

but it does not have any effect. Also I need the foreground color as it is (non-black), just the graphic should be affected by the change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The included PDF file does not contain a color operator. Driver `pdftex.def` does not set a default color by default, thus the current color is used.
The behavior of driver `pdftex.def` can be changed by setting `resetcolor`, either as option in `\includegraphics` or via:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{resetcolor}
```

However, this will not work here, because the normal color is red in this beamer document, see `fg=red`. But, the traditional `\textcolor{black}{...}` helps:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textcolor{black}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{dummy.pdf}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Note this can be done globally with the following:

`\LetLtxMacro\latexincludegraphics\includegraphics`
`\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\textcolor{black}{\latexincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}`