# preserve colors in tikz when changing slide color in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I draw and compile tikz pictures standalone:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [<->,thick] 
        (0,5) node (yaxis) [left] {$Y$}
        |- 
        (5,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$X$};
\draw[blue,thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and then include the pdf in a beamer presentation with the usual white background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics{tikz_pic.pdf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and it works fine:

[image]

But if I change the slide background to black (via `\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white, bg=black}`) it inverts the tikz picture too:

[image]

How can I preserve the colors in the tikz picture while changing the slide color?

Note that the same thing happens if you line-in the tikz code to beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw [<->,thick] 
            (0,5) node (yaxis) [left] {$Y$}
            |- 
            (5,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$X$};
    \draw[blue,thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I know you can add `[background rectangle/.style={fill=white}, show background rectangle]` to the tikz picture call and explicitly color lines black:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=white}, show background rectangle]
 \draw [<->,thick,black] 
      (0,5) node (yaxis) [left] {$Y$}
        |- 
        (5,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$X$};
\draw[blue,thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but this also does not work:

[image]

Note that this will work if you directly input the tikz code into the frame, but this is very cumbersome when you have many pictures, as it requires completely re-writing a slide deck.

What is odd is that even when the axes are explicitly drawn black, they inherit the beamer text color (white). Yet if you draw the axes in any other color (e.g. gray), they do not inherit the slide text color.

Comment: No, the solution provided in that post does not work.

Comment: @invictus the textcolour solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336394/36296 works just fine

Comment: @samcarter no, it doesn't. In my MWE there is no change. I don't know why you suggest setting the background to red and the text color to black when the question clearly states the slide background should be black.

Comment: @Kpym I tried that but it also doesn't work. See my edit to the post.

Comment: @Kpym Yes, look at the updated screenshot.

Comment: @Kpym It does not work when I compile the picture standalone. For some reason, the axes, but only the axes, inherit the beamer text color. Entering the tikz code directly into the slide works, but this is not a great solution since I have many pictures.

Comment: I deleted my comments, as I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I transform my comment to an answer.

Your image is transparent. You can fill a rectangle in the background, for example by using `backgrounds` library and adding the style `[background rectangle/.style= {fill=white},show background rectangle]`.

And your first draw command is using the default color (that usually is black), you can put `\draw [black,<->,thick] ...`.

The image (`tikz_pic.tex`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=white}, show background rectangle]
  \draw [<->,thick,black]
      (0,5) node (yaxis) [left] {$Y$} |- (5,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$X$};
  \draw[blue,thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The Beamer file is unchanged :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white, bg=black}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \includegraphics{tikz_pic.pdf}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly use black as colour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white, bg=black}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textcolor{black}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw [<->,thick] 
            (0,5) node (yaxis) [left] {$Y$}
            |- 
            (5,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$X$};
    \draw[blue,thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Of course you won't see the black axis on a black background, but you wanted them black ....

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if you set the background to black! I don't know why you set it to red.

Comment: @invictus I set it red to still have your black axis visible.

Comment: Ok but that ignores away the problem